# Expand macro immediately in \pagenote

Tags: memoir, expansion, pagenote

I'm trying to use the contents of a macro in a `\pagenote`, using the `memoir` class:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\makepagenote

\def\myvar{Good morning.}

\begin{document}

In the morning\pagenote{\myvar}

\def\myvar{Good night.}

At night\pagenote{\myvar}

\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

However, `\myvar` is written into the `.ent` file verbatim and unexpanded. As a result, the page notes show up in the final PDF as

> 1. Good night.
> 2. Good night.

Instead of the expected

> 1. Good morning.
> 2. Good night.

Is there anyway I can expand macros in `\pagenote`?

Comment: If `\myvar` is the only or at the least the first content of `\pagenote` then `\expandafter\pagenote\expandafter{\myvar}` should work. This could be wrapped up in a new macro if you need it more often.

Comment: How about `\newcommand\mypagenote[1]{\expandafter\pagenote\expandafter{#1}}`?

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks, that worked! (I had a typo in my previous attempt.) I seem to have run into further problems though, when trying to use `\mypagenote` in the definition of another macro. Perhaps it's better if I consider some approach other than pagenotes.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what exactly are trying to do. I'm sure the issues can be resolved then.

Comment: @cgnieder Sorry, my bad! I've just realised that everything (including your solution for when `\myvar` is the first content) works in a MWE, but fails in my main project code. I'll try to isolate what and where I messed up, before asking another question.

Comment: @cgnieder The error has been cleared up! Thanks again for your encouragement; I would've abandoned `\pagenote` if not for your final comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues to solve. The `\pagenote` command is built precisely in order to *avoid* expansion of its argument. Thus a “naive” definition such as

```
\newcommand{\xpagenote}[1]{%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pagenote{#1}}\x}
```

that should expand everything expandable in the argument to `\xpagenote`, passing the token list thus obtained, which is the standard way to cope with this case, doesn't work, because in the endnote file every space is changed into a new line character and there are *two* of them in case of an input such as

```
\xpagenote{\textbf{\myvar}}
```

A slightly more complicated approach seems to work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagenote

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xpagenote}[1]{%
  \unskip\begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\pagenote{#1}}%
  \scantokens\expandafter{\x\relax}}
\makeatother

\def\myvar{Good morning.}

\begin{document}

In the morning\xpagenote{Something with ``\myvar''}

\def\myvar{Good night.}

At night\xpagenote{``\textbf{\myvar}''}

\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

The pass through `\scantokens` reduces again multiple spaces to single space tokens; the final `\relax` is used to suppress the final space added by `\scantokens`.

[image]

If your `\pagenote` command contains *only* the variable, a simpler approach works:

```
\newcommand{\sxpagenote}[1]{\expandafter\pagenote\expandafter{#1}}
```

and `\sxpagenote{\myvar}` will do the right thing.